# Auth with Google or Facebook with Socialite / Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

I'm using social auth with Socialite / Laravel 5 ( Google & FB)

With Google, I can make it work in local,

I define Redirect URL to :

```
http://laravel.dev:8000/auth/login/google
```

in Google Console

But then, when I try to configure server access, I put

```
https://example.com/auth/login/google
```

I get:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

In my code, I've put a .env variable

```
APP_BASE = https://example.com
```

And in config/services.php

I have :

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('URL_BASE').'auth/login/google',
]
```

Once more, this works great in local...

What's wrong with my code???

Comment: are you able to solve this? I am getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think `env('URL_BASE')` should be `env('APP_URL')`.